# Need some explanation behind how the base type is affected by qualifiers and compound types

Tags: c++, pointers, types

I'm in the process of learning C++ and I came across this, I just need it explained, I'm guessing I need to read over my books.

All below are legal.

```
int a, b = 5, c = 10;
int a = 0, *b = &a, &c = a;
int a, *const b = &a, c = 10;
```

But doing this is illegal, or at least 'b' isn't now a const.

```
int a = 0, const b = 5, c = 0;
```

*Edit, I think I've got it myself, it's because a pointer is an object where as the likes of 'b' is just an identifier.

Comment: Well yes, the its `const int b` not `int const b`

Comment: But why can I declare a nonconst int, then declare a const pointer. But not declare a nonconst int and then a const int.

Comment: Could it be "warning C4228: nonstandard extension used : qualifiers after comma in declarator list are ignored"?

Comment: That's just how the grammar for declarators work.

Comment: I think I've got it myself, it's because a pointer is an object where as the likes of 'b' is just an identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a result of the way declarations are constructed. A *simple-declaration* (the type we are concerned with here) is

> *decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> init-declarator-list<sub>opt</sub>* ;

An *init-declarator-list* is just a comma-separated list of *init-declarator*s, and an *init-declarator* is a *declarator* followed by an optional *initializer*.

In `int const b = 5` (which *is* totally valid), the `const` (along with `int`) is part of the *decl-specifier-seq*; the `b = 5` is the *init-declarator* - the `b` is the *declarator*, the `= 5` is the *initializer*.

In `int * const b = 0;`, however, the *decl-specifier-seq* is just `int`; the *declarator* is `* const b` -  the `* const` together is a *ptr-operator*, which is part of the declarator.

`const b` is not a valid declarator, and so `int a = 0, const b = 5, c = 0;` is invalid. `* const b` is a valid declarator, so `int a, *const b = &a, c = 10;` is valid.